# CORS issue on same domain Ajax/PHP

Tags: php, ajax, cors, http-headers

I'm facing a CORS problem with an ajax call.
I have a php file called through ajax with the following headers

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * ');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, ADD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *'); // also tested with Content-Type, x-requested-with
```

There is no error when the file is called from

```
http://www.mywebsite.com
```

but it throws a 403 forbidden error when it's called from

```
https://mywebsite.com
https://www.mywebsite.com
```

To be more specific the GET is ok, but the ADD is not allowed.
As we're talking about the same domain, i don't understand why there's a '403' error

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Using method `ADD` means this won't be a [simple request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests) any more, but one that causes a [preflighted request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests) - so your server side logic would need to handle that correctly as well.

Comment: But this doesn't sound like a scenario where I'd bother with implementing CORS to begin with. _Why_ is your site reachable via both the prefix-less and the www-prefixed host name to begin with? Usually, you'd decide on one version to use, and create an automatic redirect if the other one was requested ... And even if that is not an option, then assuming that your endpoint is reachable via both as well, it would perhaps still make more sense to use a _relative_ URL for your request then, so that it won't ever be cross-origin either.

Comment: Yea, might be preflight. Btw I hear ADD method for first time, is this really correct in the first place? https://dariuscoder.com/2021/09/16/how-to-debug-cors/ you can see example with preflight there on nginx. To get better help - tell us what server do you use, add server config.

Answer (score -1):

what php framework
if this is laravel you are using make sure you see the file config/cors.php
or the file VerifyCsrfToken

```php
     protected $except = [
        '*'
    ];
```